# How to insert a row if the value from other table doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have three tables: `person`, `lead` and `legal_entity`.
`legal_entity.personId` references `person.Id` and `lead.personId` also references `person.Id`.
What I need to do is to insert a new row with the value of `legal_entity.personId` to the `lead` table if it doesn't exist already. I need to do it for every row from `legal_entity` table. I have no idea how to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO lead (person_id)
SELECT p.id
FROM legal_entity le
INNER JOIN person p on le.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN lead l on p.id = l.person_id
WHERE l.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation rather than just posting code.